# How to solve this recursive function puzzle?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

During interview in a company, interviewer ask me this question.

Suppose we have a array like this:

```
int[] arr = {2,12,14,-16,18,22,45};
```

They told me to code a function for get sum of array.

So how can I get sum of this array, by using function, with below given conditions:

Condition 1: I can't use any global variable. Means array is also define inside function.

Condition 2: And I must use recursive function.

Coding should be in java.

I did not post code here because this question was ask to me during interview and I was not able to found solution for this problem. I found some solutions on stackoverflow but in those solutions no one define array inside the function.

Comment: Asking this kind of question without showing any effort is not good.

Comment: what have you attempted so far. Post your code

Comment: Apparently this got two upvotes somehow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253651/recursively-sum-the-integers-in-an-array

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Comment: "I can't use any global variable." That is not a bad thing. "Means array is also define inside function." This is false. Parameters are made just for that. They are not global variables! How would your method know what to calculate? Besides it would defy everything I know about programming...

Comment: The only way I can think of an array defined inside the method is a main method. It wouldn't be dynamic but it's defined in the method.

Comment: My Friend open link suggest by Fast Snail   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253651/recursively-sum-the-integers-in-an-array

Comment: there is not any condition for not using parameters

Answer (score 2):

do something likewise,

```
int[] arr = {2,12,-6};

System.out.println(recur(arr, arr.length-1)); // output : 8
```

.......

```
int recur(int arr[] , int lastindex){

        if(lastindex == 0 ){
            return arr[lastindex];
        }

        return arr[lastindex] + recur(arr, lastindex-1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int sum(int[] array, int index) {
    if (index >= array.length)
        return 0;
    else
        return array[index] + sum(array, index + 1);
}
```

and

```
    int[] arr = {2,12,14,-16,18,22,45};
    System.out.println(sum(arr, 0));
    // -> 97
```

Comment: You do not need a total variable, just return the sum and it will be calculated recursively

Comment: @YassinHajaj Thanks!