# Errors in toString method and Recursion method that returns sum of array

Tags: java, arrays, object, recursion

I'm working on the following problem:

***Write an object class with just one instance variable, an integer array.  Your constructor should take an integer array  as its only parameter.  Write all the accessors, mutators, toString and equals methods.  Also write an additional RECURSIVE method that returns the sum of all the elements in the array (your method should have an array as it's argument and should have the recursive call in its return for the general case).  Write a client class to test all your methods and especially your recursive method.***

For some reason, I have an error in my toString method, and I also have an error in my recursion method that is supposed to return the sum of the array. I may be way off with some of this code so any help is appreciated.

***Here is what I have so far...***

***CLIENT CLASS (USED TO TEST METHODS)***

```
package weeklylab9;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectClass numArray = new ObjectClass; //trying to create new object so I can use toString method
        numArray.toString(); //calling toString method?
    }
}
```

***OBJECT CLASS***

```
package weeklylab9;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ObjectClass {
    int[] numArray = {10,10,20,20,40};

    public int[] getArray() { //this is my accessor method
        return numArray;
    }

    public int[] setArray(int[] newa) { //this is my mutator method
        this.numArray = newa;
        return this.numArray;
    }

    public String toString() { //this is my toString method
        Arrays.toString(int[], numArray);
    }

    public int recursionSum(int[] numArray) { //this should be a recursion method that returns sum of array elements
        int sum = IntStream.of(numArray).sum();
        System.out.println("The sum is : " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate it when teachers give assignments asking students to use recursion for non-recursive problems.  It leads to thinking recursion is the solution for everything.  Same for regexp.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is; also please update your post and correct the code formatting.

Comment: in toString() method Im getting error that says:

-Syntax error, insert ".class" to complete argument list
-The method toString(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Class <int>, int[])
-line breakpoint:ObjectClass [line 20] - toString()

Comment: ... error that says what?

Comment: sorry, I keep hitting enter instead of shift+enter,

Comment: Should be `return Arrays.toString(numArray);`

Comment: @KalaBalik i just tried that and now I get: "This method must return a result of type String" and another that says: "overrides java.lang.Object.toString"

Comment: For the first error: please check again; for the second warning: You can add @Override in the line above the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toString() method should look like this:

```
public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(numArray);
}
```

You were missing the return statement and your call to `Arrays.toString()` had an additional and wrong argument.

Calculating a sum with recursion is pretty pointless, but here is a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20253717/8883654